# "They are all Father for Sam Parkers blog..." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm transcribing [an interview](https://transfernow.net/91hyn1v54663):

> Whether ("Why do", the host speaks very fast, therefore I'm not sure)we are on the internet watching TV or pushing a shopping cart down the store aisles consumers are constantly inundated with marketing pitches and they are all **Father for** the Sam Parker's blog and his new book retail NRK its retail critic and consumer anthropologist came into our New York studios to share his concerns.
>   ...

What's he saying? Is there an expression like this? He's talking too fast, therefore, maybe I made a mistake, while I was transcribing.

NOTE: You can download [this interview](https://transfernow.net/91hyn1v54663). (it's in the first 20 seconds)

Comment: It's *whether* at the beginning of the sentence. (*Whether* we are on the internet watching TV *or*...)

Comment: By the way, I think it's "marketing pitches" not *marketing pictures*.

Comment: You're right @helen, but what are marketing pitches? Are they sales pitches(a presentation of a product or a service to the customers to make them aware of the product benefits and close the purchase deal)?

Comment: I haven't listened but it's probably **fodder**.

Comment: -1. If you're going to ask us to listen to something, tell us where the phrase occurs, e.g. 3:15.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi Yes, it's a commercial in which you talk about a product you want to sell in order to persuade people to buy it.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo +1 for fodder. And it's in the beginning(first 20 seconds), so this problem is not taking up too much of your time, you're right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

the word is indeed Fodder

> **fodder**
>
> NOUN mass noun
>
> 1 Food, especially dried hay or straw, for cattle and other livestock.
>
> Synonyms
>
> 1.1 A person or thing regarded only as material for a specific use.
>
> ‘young people ending up as factory fodder’

[oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fodder)

Cambridge has a better second definition for this case

> people or things that are useful for the stated purpose:
>
> Politicians are always good fodder for comedians (= they make jokes
>   about them).

[cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fodder)

This is using the word fodder in the synonym way, it is meaning all of the different marketing "pitches" are good ways of advertising Sam Parker's book/ blog

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi You may want to stop using the name dear for people  it can be taken as very patronising. Here is a good news article https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-13211577

Comment: I've actually heard this use can sometimes sound rather patronising, but I often use this word when speaking in a friendly way to someone. Anyway, I didn’t mean to sound patronising, sir.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi you have now been told twice it sounds patronising, please listen to both people and stop.  It isn't friendly unless you know the person really well and know they like it.  Do not use it on strangers on the internet.

Comment: You're right, I will change my tune.